# Trouble Understanding Proof: Proving Chain is Markov Chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm having trouble understanding this proof:
[image]

There's a couple of things that do not make sense to me.

1. I do not understand why:
   $
   X_{n+1}=
   \begin{cases}
    X_n-1, \text{if}\ X_n \geq 1\\
    Y_{K_{n+1}}-1, \text{if}\ X_n=0\\
   \end{cases}
   $

I think the transition probabilities, $P_{0,j}=P(Y_1=j+1)$, $P_{j+1,j}=1$ for all $j \geq 0$, are derived using the above formulation so I really want to understand why $
X_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
 X_n-1, \text{if}\ X_n \geq 1\\
 Y_{K_{n+1}}-1, \text{if}\ X_n=0\\
\end{cases}$

2. I don't how we can solve $\pi P=\pi$ to deduce $\pi_{i}=\frac{P(Y_1>i)}{\mu}$. I tried solving $\pi P=\pi$ but I couldn't do it, I tried setting up the equations, but there is an infinite number of states so I didn't know how to solve for the stationary distribution. Is there some trick to do it?

Out of these two questions, the first question, question 1 is what I'm more concerned with, as I really want to understand why its true, although it would also be nice to understand my second question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X_n = 0$. This is equivalent to $$Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} = n. \tag{$*$}$$
This implies $Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} + Y_{K_n + 1} \ge n+1$, and  $$X_{n+1} = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} + Y_{K_n + 1} - (n+1) = Y_{K_n + 1} - 1,$$
where the last equality is due to substituting ($*$).

---

Suppose $X_n \ge 1$. Since $$X_n = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} - n,\tag{$**$}$$ this is equivalent to
$$Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} \ge n + 1. $$
Thus
$$X_{n+1} = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_{K_n} - (n + 1) = X_n - 1,$$
where the last equality is due to substituting ($**$).

---

$\pi P = \pi$ can be written as
$$\pi_j = \sum_{i \ge 0} \pi_i p_{i,j}
= P(Y_1 = j + 1) \pi_0 + \pi_{j+1},
\qquad \forall j \ge 0.$$
You can use this to show by induction that $\pi_j = P(Y_1 > j) \pi_0$ for $j \ge 1$.
Then using $\sum_{j \ge 1} \pi_j = 1$ you can show that $\pi_0 = 1/\mu$.